# Unable to use System.Threading.Tasks in WP7 application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, task-parallel-library

I recently completed a library for a online storage website that allows for me to call the PHP exposed RESTs between the file storage website and a windows form desktop client + Outlook add in.

Now, here is a question that has the code sample for the most basic operation in the library: [Gracefully killing a TPL Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090932/gracefully-killing-a-tpl-task). I'm linking it for reference only. My next objective is a Windows Phone 7 client.

I knew I simply cannot use the same library as I need a different kind of class library for a WP7 app. So i went forward and created a WP7 version of the library hoping most of the stuff will work. I hit a road block immediately when I realized that I don't have access to the most critical class: a TPL Task.

Am I missing something here? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

OK. Apparently, there is no official System.Threading.Tasks for a WP7 project. However, after getting proper sleep and searching again, i found that a package exists at NuGet that simply answers all my needs: [Task Parallel Library for Silverlight](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/System.Threading.Tasks). The version is at 2.1.2 at the time of writing.

Answer (score 8):

Since Hasan answered the question, an official way has popped up.  If you are targetting Windows Phone 7.5, the new **official** way of doing it would be to get the Microsoft.Bcl.  This also works for .NET Framework 4 and Silverlight 4/5.  I have only personally used it for .NET Portable Class Libraries and Windows Phone projects.

[Microsoft.Bcl is available on the Nuget website](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) or by running this command in your Package Manager console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl
```